# How to set cursor movement hotkeys in tmux?

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I use iTerm2 as my go-to terminal. I also like to use tmux.

However, tmux overrides my iTerm configuration at times, which is annoying.

For example I have iTerm set so `command-left_arrow` will jump the cursor to the beginning of the line (useful for prepending `sudo` to commands, and `command-right_arrow` jumps the cursor to the end of the line.

However, in tmux, this feature is gone. Ideally, I'd be able to set this behavior in my tmux config, so that any terminal that I use could use that feature, rather than just when I am using iTerm2 on my mac.

Any ideas?